# dojo file upload with dojo.io.iframe.send

Tags: file-upload, dojo

I have tried to upload file using dojo.xhrPost and couldn't. Then tried dojo.io.iframe.send it works but it results to a normal form submit. Can any one explain to me how the dojo.io.iframe.send works.